# Unable to add Firebase to 2 module LibGDX project

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle, libgdx

I've been trying to add Firebase Database to my school project, that uses LibGDX. It has 2 subproject modules: "core" and "android".

When trying to implement com.google.firebase:firebase-database to my gradle files, I can only access the Firebase functions from the "android" module, which basically has no code. When I compile the library in the core/build.gradle, I get this error: Module depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar.

I tried using every other library that implements Firebase, without much success. I've included my gradle codes in the bottom.

Thanks!!

Here are my gradle codes:

**core/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]


eclipse.project {
    name = appName + "-core"
}
dependencies{
    compile "de.tomgrill.gdxfirebase:gdx-firebase-android:0.0.4-SNAPSHOT"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**project/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {


    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "mygame"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.7'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.1'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"

    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "net.dermetfan.libgdx-utils:libgdx-utils-box2d:0.13.4"
        compile "net.dermetfan.libgdx-utils:libgdx-utils:0.13.4"

    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    compileSdkVersion 23
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/robovm/ios/robovm.xml'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.extelite.mygame"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() { 
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")        
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if(outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.extelite.mygame/com.extelite.mygame.AndroidLauncher'
}

// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitly, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [ project.configurations.compile ]        
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'       
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}

// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [ COMPILE: [plus:[project.configurations.compile]]]        

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value:"true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
}
apply plugin 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is platform related library. It have different implementation for Android and IOS operating systems. *Core* module should contain only common business logic, but you can create an *MyDatabase* interface in this module and implement it separately in certain platforms.

First of all, you need to create holder class for `MyDatabase` implementation in core module:

```
public class MyDatabaseHolder {

    private static MyDatabase DB;

    public static void setDb(MyDatabase db) {
        DB = db;
    }

    public static MyDatabase getDb(MyDatabase db) {
        return DB;
    }

    public interface MyDatabase {
        void saveString(String string);
    }
}
```

Now you can use it to access `MyDatabase` instance in *core module*:

```
public class MyCoreClass {

    public void test() {
        MyDatabaseHolder.getDb().saveString("It works!");
    }
}
```

Implementation of `MyDatabase` and initialization `MyDatabaseHolder` will be in Android (or IOS) module:

Implementation:

```
public class AndroidDatabase implements MyDatabase {

    @Override
    public void saveString(String string) {
        // here you have access to Firebase API
    }
}
```

Initialization:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyDatabaseHolder.setDb(new AndroidDatabase());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on that? I don't really understand what you mean by "Core module should contain only common business logic". And if I create an interface in "Core", it still doesn't recognize Firebase.

Comment: @YoavGilad I have write code to explain main idea. Check it

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Unfortunately, I don't think that's the way to go. I can't access Firebase(MyDatabase, I think?) from the core module at all. As it's not implemented in the module, I can't reference it anywhere in core.

Comment: @YoavGilad you don't need directly use Firebase API in core module. In core you just use interface `MyDatabase` with required method signature. Implementation of `MyDatabase` (`AndroidDatabase` class) have full access to Firebase - write Firebase related code here